# Find the number of ways in which 4 letters can be selected from the 9 letters of the word ALGORITHM, given at least one vowel is included.

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

My solution:

3 cases:

1 vowel:

$6P3 \times 3C1 = 360 $

2 vowels:

$6P2 \times 3C2 \times 2! = 180 $

3 vowels:

$6P1 \times 3! = 36 $

Total number of ways: 360 + 180 + 36 = 576

Am I correct?

Comment: It isn't clear why you're mixing the xPy with the xCy. One of them counts differently ordered with same letters as distinct, the other does not.  The statement of the problem, to me, seems to imply that the number desired is combinations not permutations, i.e. order irrelevant, only what letters chosen.

Answer (score 1):

Taking the header to be right, your answer is wrong !

Do pay heed to the exact wordings of questions.

It reads "... $4$ letters can be **selected** ...."

There is a difference between *selection* and *arrangement*

Btw, even had the question been about arrangements, your answer would have been wrong.

*Added Guidance*

Assuming it *was* about arrangements, the first case would have been $^6C_3\times^3C_1\times 4!$

And if it was about *selections*, just $^6C_3\times^3C_1$

As a final word of guidance for **at least** types of questions, it is better to work with the complement of the desired event, so if we want, for example, P(at least one vowel), compute  $1-$ P(no vowel)

Comment: May I know what have I done wrong?

Comment: I have given added guidance

Comment: Then the final result for selected shall be ($^6C_3\times^3C_1$) + ($^6C_2\times^3C_2$) + ($^6C_1\times^3C_3$) . Is it correct?

Comment: Yes, but more easily, $^9C_4 - ^6C_4$

Comment: thank you very much

Comment: You are welcome !

Answer (score 0):

Using the Inclusion-Exclusion principle, we count the number of combinations that use $1$ vowel, subtract those that use $2$, and add those that use all $3$.

The generating function for this is

$$[x^4]:(1-(1-x)^3)\frac{1}{(1-x)^6}$$

where

$$1-(1-x)^3=\binom{3}{1}x-\binom{3}{1}x^2+x^3$$

$$\frac{1}{(1-x)^6}=\binom{5}{5}+\binom{6}{5}x+\binom{7}{5}x^2+\binom{8}{5}x^3+\dots$$

and gives $3\cdot56-3\cdot21+6=111$.

Also, the GF can be re-arranged to give

$$[x^4]:\frac{1}{(1-x)^6}-\frac{(1-x)^3}{(1-x)^6}$$

$$[x^4]:\frac{1}{(1-x)^6}-\frac{1}{(1-x)^3}$$

$$=\binom{9}{5}-\binom{6}{2}$$

$$=111$$